# Two postback buttons ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have two simple pages. Page 1 postbacks to page 2. I have two buttons that can cause a postback, Confirm and Delete. On page 2 there are two buttons; one saves the passed data, and the other deletes the passed data. What I need to do is have the unneeded button on page 2 set to visible = false. How can I set up different actions based on which button caused the postback?

Comment: How exactly does the request to Page 2 get made?  Does the client-side form actually post to Page 2, or does a server-side action on Page 1 redirect to Page 2?  However the request is made, you can include some kind of flag on the request (form value, query string value, etc.) that Page 2 can check for.

Comment: I set the PostBackUrl for the button<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update Account Information" PostBackUrl="~/pg2.aspx"  /> and added <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/pg1.aspx" %> to the page1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use Query string to indicate the page to show the appropriate button in your second page 
ex : http:\localhost\page1.aspx?show=delete

at the other hand, in your page2 "page_load" function you could manage the code to show the button based on query string requested along with the request url

the code will be something like this on your Page_Load:

```
string showButton = Request.QueryString["show"];
if(showButton == "delete")
{
// write the code to show the delete button here
}
```

Comment: change your postback url to like this PostBackUrl="~/pg2.aspx?show=delete" or PostBackUrl="~/pg2.aspx?show=confirm"

Comment: Excellent. I knew there was an easy solution. Thank you, this was perfect!